# First steps with Polymer, elements not displaying correctly (in Plunker!)

Tags: polymer

I'm just starting with web development, and I'm trying to use some polymer elements:

http://embed.plnkr.co/o4OKkE/

I'm kind of half managing the import. The elements display (in some manner). The paper element works well, apart from the margins. The button is good, the paper-input completely fails, same with tabs. The text/formatting is all default. Does polymer dictate the font etc, or is it managed using CSS separately?

I think I'm not attaching the theme correctly. Can anyone point out the errors?

---

**Edit:** Thanks to Neil John Ramal, I've got the basics working without any errors:

http://run.plnkr.co/AD3ETQOsMwajnSBt/

I just can't seem to get the elements to import using polygit, just rawgit.

This here:

works fine. However this produces an error:

> Redirect at origin 'http://polygit.org' has been blocked from loading by Cross-Origin Resource Sharing policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://run.plnkr.co' is therefore not allowed access.

Presumably because Plunker is not allowing redirects and that's how polygit works. How it functions with polymer.html I'm not sure...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are mixing up your imports. You have to make sure you are importing your components from a single source so no variable/name clashing would occur. On your example, you are importing both from your own repository and polygit's.

Evidence is on the error logs:

```
VM199 polymer-micro.html:363 Uncaught NotSupportedError: Failed to execute 'registerElement' on 'Document': Registration failed for type 'dom-module'. A type with that name is already registered.
```

This just means that you have imported `polymer.html` more than once and from different sources. HTML imports only dedupe if they came from the same source.

Also at your `index.html`:

```
<script data-require="polymer@*" data-semver="1.0.0" src="http://polygit.org/components/polymer/polymer.html"></script>
```

Should be:

```
<link rel="import" src="//polygit.org/components/polymer/polymer.html">
```

Comment: Things are working much better now, but the theming still doesn't seem to be being applied (see edit).